# Could Goku have been revived if he really wanted, after dying fighting Cell?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

After defeating Cell, they revived all his victims using Shenron. But Shenron could not revive Goku, as he already revived once. Then, Goku contacted them using King Kai's telepathy and asked them not to revive him.

The question is, would it have been possible to revive him somehow (at that point of the story) if he were not against it?

Comment: please accept an answer when you feel that they answer your question. When you don't feel that, then provide more information, ask as comment the answer more details or such.

Answer (score 7):

Unlike the Dragon Balls on Earth, the Dragon Balls of Namek are not restricted to reviving someone once. During the fight with Kid Buu, Goku and all the people Buu killed on Earth as well as the planet itself were revived by having the Namekians collect the Dragon Balls.

So yes, Goku could and was revived again by the Namekian Dragon Balls.

Comment: Yes, the question is, how could they have accessed/communicated to the Namekians at that point of the story? (by the way, Goku was not revived using the Dragon Balls from Namek, he was revived by Rō Kaiō Shin :))

Comment: Oh ya the Kaioshin was the one that revived him. Regardless, Goku and a few others can communicate directly to the Namekians using telepathy.

Answer (score 2):

1. Goku brought Dende to earth before he died in the fight against Cell, so they got two wishes. So, they could have used the second wish to go to Namek, then use one wish there to revive Goku and Kaito and use another to go back to earth.
2. Goku could have communicated with the Namekians to ask them to revive him.
3. Dende could have changed the Dragon Balls to make such wishes come true. Note that the Namekians made Porunga (Namekian Dragon) more powerful, so that he can revive multiple persons with one wish.
4. They could use the stupid-looking idea from Krillin and just turn back time multiple days so that Goku could train more and could even beat Cell, then he wouldn't die in the first place.

So yes, there would have been multiple ways to revive Goku at this time.

Comment: Or you could use the BlackStarDragonBalls when you include DBGT, but nobody includes DBGT :P

Answer (score -2):

Goku couldn't have been revived because there were no dragon balls and no one knew were new namek was,and instant transmission was still limited by distance so even if Goku wanted to be brought back to life there would still be no possible way. Even if you include GT Goku was still brought back to life once so the black star dragon balls could not have brought Goku back to life.